# How can I perform unicast communication in Veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

While looking for various information on Stackoverflow, I read that `Veins 5.x` and above support `Unicast communication`.

I understood that unicast communication is possible through `populateWSM()`. However, I don't understand which `LAddress::L2Type rcvId` should be in the `ID` value of the second parameter.

Should I pass the `ID` value obtained through

```
getParentModule() -> getIndex()
```

Or is it necessary to pass the `ID` value of the left node list when running the simulation? If it's the latter, how can I get the `ID` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo implementation of Veins 5.1 uses the OMNeT++ module ID. For more robustness, I would recommend querying the MAC layer. See, for example, https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.1/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/DemoBaseApplLayer.cc#L83

Comment: The information was really helpful. But how can I pass the mac value of `LAddress::L2Type` to another node? It seems that the data type is not defined in the `.msg` file.

Comment: You will find this information in the OMNeT++ user manual if you look for “noncobject” (that is, how to define message field types that are not cObject derived types)